# Angular ajax working only with $timeout in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive which makes an ajax request.
It's not work until I wrap it inside a $timeout like here:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            param1: '=',
            param2: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "teams/views/myDirective.html",
        link: function($scope){
            $timeout(function(){
                $http.get(endPointUrl)
                    .success(function(result){
                        console.log(result)
                    })
                    .error(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
```

Do anybody have the idea why?
Thanks the answers in advance!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it should work. Something else is going on in the code that you haven't posted.

Comment: well, the fact is there are a lots of directives (5-6) which makes ajax requests too. Do you think it can affect the behaviour of the normal data flow?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal data flow". Do you see any errors in the console? Btw, here's your [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/1yNlxnZsyudg2mwnOqXp?p=preview) adjusted for illustrative purposes that works.

Comment: well, you might right. My problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: You should then either amend the question or better yet - delete, and create a new one that isolates the problem better.

Comment: Since it's not clear where `endPointUrl` comes from we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` call just returns the promise.
Following code may help you.
Ideally, fetching data like operations should be done in services instead of directive's link function.

```
app.service('myService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.getData = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://httpbin.org/get',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': "application/json"
        }
      }).
      success(function(data, status) {
        return data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status) {
        return "Request Failed";
      });

    }
  }
]);

app.directive('appDirective', ['myService',
  function(myService) {
    return {
      link: function($scope) {
        myService.getData().then(function(data) {
          $scope.name = 'User, Data fetched as: ' + JSON.stringify(data);
        })
      }

    }
  }
])
```

working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/stdJxAnHINORI06pPZJX?p=preview